# Composite Key Problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am making an MVC application that takes daily user input and puts it in a table. It is sorted into days, weeks and months and I am trying out composite keys but am getting an error.

Here are my models:

`Year` model:

```
public class Year
{
    [ForeignKey("YearID")]
    public int YearID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

`Week` model:

```
public class Week
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int WeekID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int YearID { get; set; }

    public virtual Year year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, `Day` model:

```
public class Day
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int DayID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int WeekID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int YearID { get; set; }

    public float Reading1 { get; set; }
    public float Reading2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Week Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

`UtilityInitializer` class:

```
namespace Utility3.DAL
{
    public class UtilityInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UtilityContext>
        {
        protected override void Seed(UtilityContext context)
        {
            var years = new List<Year>
            {
                new Year{YearID = 2014},
                new Year{YearID = 2015}
            };
            years.ForEach(s => context.Years.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var weeks = new List<Week>
            {
                new Week{WeekID = 1, YearID = 2014},
                new Week{WeekID = 2, YearID = 2014},
                new Week{WeekID = 1, YearID = 2015},
                new Week{WeekID = 2, YearID = 2015}
            };
            weeks.ForEach(s => context.Weeks.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var days = new List<Day>
            {
                new Day{DayID = 1, WeekID = 1, YearID = 2014},
                new Day{DayID = 2, WeekID = 1, YearID = 2014},
                new Day{DayID = 1, WeekID = 2, YearID = 2014},
                new Day{DayID = 2, WeekID = 2, YearID = 2014},
                new Day{DayID = 1, WeekID = 1, YearID = 2015},
                new Day{DayID = 2, WeekID = 1, YearID = 2015},
                new Day{DayID = 1, WeekID = 2, YearID = 2015},
                new Day{DayID = 2, WeekID = 2, YearID = 2015}

            };

            days.ForEach(s => context.Days.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
}
```

When I try to make the controllers I get this error:

`Unable to retrieve metadata from "Utility3.Models.Year". The property "YearID" cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.`

I have `YearID` as a foreign key in an attempt to fix the problem. I got a different error without the foreign key.

Why is the YearID throwing that error?

**EDIT**
I tried changing the name in the `Week` model of `YearID` to `YearNo` and changed this segment of code in my initializer:

```
var weeks = new List<Week>
        {
            new Week{YearNo = years.Single(i => i.YearID == 2014).YearID, WeekID = 1},
            new Week{YearNo = years.Single(i => i.YearID == 2014).YearID, WeekID = 2},
            new Week{YearNo = years.Single(i => i.YearID == 2015).YearID, WeekID = 1},
            new Week{YearNo = years.Single(i => i.YearID == 2015).YearID, WeekID = 2}
        };
        weeks.ForEach(s => context.Weeks.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

But now it is telling me that the sequence contains no matching elements but there is?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting without the `[ForeignKey]` attribute on `YearID`? Did you try to set that as the `[Key]` on the class as well?

Comment: When I take out `[ForeignKey]`, I am able create the controllers for each model, then when I run the application, click on any of the tabs with "Year","Week" or "Day", I get: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Week_dbo.Year_YearID". The conflict occured in database "Utility3", table "dbo.Year", column "YearID"." It says it's in my initializer class. I'll add that code to the question.

Comment: Then try setting `YearID` as the primary key in the `Year` class.

Comment: Wrong tagging. THis is absolutely not an MVC problem but an entity framework problem.

Comment: That didn't work :/ it saying the error is in my initializer class at line 30: "weeks.ForEach(s => context.Weeks.Add(s));
            **context.SaveChanges();**"

Comment: @TomTom Sorry, I did not know.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to the models above the keys to allow me to edit them. It's working for now any way .

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a foreign key as part of a composite key on a table. Change your tables to work like this, and it will do what you want.

```
public class Year
{
    [Key]
    public int YearID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
}


public class Week
{
    [Key]
    public int WeekID { get; set; }

    public virtual Year year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    [Key]
    public int DayID { get; set; }

    public float Reading1 { get; set; }
    public float Reading2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Week Weeks { get; set; }
}
```